# How to delay rendering of DOM element to prevent unresponsiveness

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I am fetching huge list of people (1000) from server as an API call.
Based on data I have to render "cards" for each user, which will contain their name, picture, age etc.

But when I do that, browser gets stuck for a while till all the cards are rendered. Is there any way to tell browser that its not necessary to render everything at once, it can do so one by one, without crashing itself ?

Comment: use `setTimeout` adding smaller number of elements to the DOM at a time

Comment: Maybe just don't render 1000 cards to the screen? They won't be shown all at once anyway.

Comment: @Bergi: 1000 is just a random number, question is about preventing unresponsiveness due to heavy DOM manipulations.

Comment: @RahulPrasad: It's not about the number. Don't render much more than what fits on the screen, and it won't be heavy processing. Pagination has a reason.

Comment: I remember [this blog post](http://blog.fogcreek.com/we-spent-a-week-making-trello-boards-load-extremely-fast-heres-how-we-did-it/) from one of the guys working at Trello, where they improved the performance for boards with hundreds of cards (the example they use was a page rendering a board with 996 cards). In the end they divided the cards in chunks and render one chunk at a time.

Comment: Rendering huge number of content is a requirement, I cant not use pagination. I am talking about a situation where you have to render too much data.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fv9qT9joc0M&list=PL7664379246A246CB#t=4019)

If you add an element to the DOM, the page will be repainted. If you add 100 elements one by one, it will be repainted 100 times, and that's slow. Create a single container and add nodes for the items to it *before* appending it to your page.

```
var container = $('<div>');

$.each(items, function (index, itm) {
    var el = $('<div>');
    el.attr('id', ID_PREFIX + index);
    el.html(createHtml(itm));
    container.append(el);
});

$('#list-container').append(container);
```

Something like the above (using jQuery, but you can be fine with plain JS).

(of course `createHtml` is an utility function you can define to get the markup for your item and `items` is the array with your data)

That said, I agree with @Bergi above: do you really need to show all items at the same time? Could you set a scrolling view that populates as you scroll down?

Next thing you can do, use [RactiveJs](http://ractivejs.org) or [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) to efficiently manage data-binding.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options here. The best options are, as others have mentioned, not to render at all:

- Use an "infinite scroll" technique to only render what you need. The basic idea is to remove DOM elements that go offscreen and add those that come onscreen by inspecting the scroll position.
- Use a different user-driven pagination mechanism.

Barring that, you can get better performance by rendering all in one go, either through constructing and setting `innerHTML` or by using a document fragment. But with 1000's of elements, you'll still get poor performance.

At this point, you probably want **batch processing**. This won't be faster, but it will free up the UI so that things aren't locked while you're rendering. A very basic batching approach might look like this:

```
// things to render
var items = [...];
var index = 0;
var batchSize = 100;
// time between batches, in ms
var batchInterval = 100;

function renderBatch(batch) {
    // rendering logic here
}

function nextBatch() {
    var batch = items.slice(index, index + batchSize);
    renderBatch(batch);
    index += batchSize;
    if (index < items.length - 1) {
        // Render the next batch after a given interval
        setTimeout(nextBatch, batchInterval);
    }
}

// kick off
nextBatch();
```

It's worth noting, though, that there are limits to this - rendering is a bottleneck, but every DOM element is going to impact client memory too. With 10s of 1000s of elements, things will be slow and unresponsive even after rendering is complete, because the memory usage is so high.